# How to save each letter while the while loop is running

Tags: python, while-loop

```
word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')

for i in word:
    if i in ['a','e','i','u','A','E','I','O','o','U']:
        word1 = i
        break

    else:
        print i,


print ""

i = 0
while word[i]!=word1:
```

This is where I am having a problem. I need to save each letter before the vowel(or g as I have attempted). This is the beginnings of a pig latin translator. In this stage, I am trying to flip the prefix and the rest of the word.

```
    g = word[i]
    i = i+1


prefix = g + word1

print prefix
```

Example:

```
input -  person
output - rsonpe

input -  hello
output - llohe

input -  pppat
output - tpppa

input -  hhhhhelllllloool
output - llllllooolhhhhhe
```

I am flipping the letters before the first vowel, and the rest of the word.

Comment: have you tried appending to a list?

Comment: No, where could I do this with .append?

Comment: In your if statament. If you write out explicit details of the output you would like I could be more specific.

Comment: Yes, could you please be more specific. Sorry, I am only a little past a beginner.

Comment: Then update your post with example data and expected output.

Comment: Explain what it's doing, in the first example you gave it makes no sense what you're doing to the word at least it's not obvious what you're doing to the word and in the second example it loops like you're just taking the last letter and making it the first letter. Sorry, more details are always better.

Comment: i have to go now. I will continue working on this either tommorow morning

Comment: I have finished giving more examples and updated my program.

Comment: I would recommend not using `i` in two different ways. The `for` loop uses `i` as a string and the `while` loop seems to use it as an index. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regular expression if you are familiar with it or you can just edit your code like this in a very simple and crude way.

```
word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
word1 = 0
for i in range(0,len(word)) :
    if word[i] in ['a','e','i','u','A','E','I','O','o','U']:
        word1=i
        break
print word[word1+1:]+word[:word1]+word[word1]
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution, however is there a way that you could explain that last line, and save some of the elements into variables, as to make it easier to read?

Comment: i am just slicing the string in the last line. python facilitates a very easy way to do this. say for example u have a string wish='hello' to get any charector in any specific index u just have to wish[index] ex:- wish[0] will give u 'h'  and if u want to get only first 3 characters in the string you can just do wish[:3] which will give you characters from index 0 to 3(0,1,2) which is 'hel'. same way wish[3:] will give you characters in index from 4 till end of the string.  to know more about slicing a string check http://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

Comment: instead of creating a variable every time.you can save the elements you require in a list just by creating a list and appending the characters you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

Vowel = re.compile('[aeiouAEIOU]')

def flipper ( inStr ) :
    myIndex = Vowel.search( inStr ).start() + 1
    return inStr[myIndex:] + inStr[:myIndex]

flipper( 'hello' )
```

output:

```
'llohe'
```

Alternatively, if you really want to do it with a `while` loop, you just need to define a global variable outside of the `while` loop that you can save to.